# What is the "polar coordinate function"?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm reading Tapp's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces,* I have this problem:

> $\quad\color{green}{\text{Exercise 1.10.}}$ Prove that the arc length, $L$, of the graph of the polar coordinate function $r(\theta)$, $\theta \in [a, b]$, is

What is the "polar coordinate function"? I tried a few guesses but nothing I thought seemed to make sense nor would give me the arclength function above. Using the definition of arclength, I tried to "reverse engineer" it and I got:

$$\left(\int_{a}^{\theta} r(x)\, dx,\, r(\theta) \right)$$

This seems to be the only function that would make sense here but I have no idea what $r(\theta)$ would be. This is — perhaps — the least worst thing I could think of.

Comment: I think it just means a curved parameterized using polar coordinates instead of rectangular.

Comment: So, with that in mind, hint: start with the usual arc length formula, and change variables from $(x, y)$ to $(r, \theta)$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Suppose we have a curve (x(t),y(t)), using polar coordinates we get $(x,y)=(r \sin \theta, r \cos \theta)$. I'm not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 4):

It means that in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, your curve is parametrized by $$[a,b]\ni \theta \mapsto (r(\theta),\theta) \in  [0,\infty)\times [0,2\pi).\tag{1}$$Relative to cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$, it means that the parametrization is $$[a,b] \ni \theta \mapsto (r(\theta)\cos\theta, r(\theta)\sin\theta) \in \Bbb R^2.\tag{2}$$Surely you can compute the arclength of $(2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Arc length for a curve $C$ in the plane looks like
$$
L = \int_C \mathrm{d}s, 
$$
which you're probably more familiar with when the curve is parametrized, i.e.  the cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ are expressed as functions of a parameter $t \in [a, b]$:
$$
L = \int_a^b \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} \, \mathrm{d}t. 
$$

This formula comes from the chain rule
$$
\mathrm{d}x = x'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\mathrm{d}y = y'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t, 
$$
together with what is essentially the Pythagorean theorem for differentials,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}s^2 &= \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 \\
&= \bigl( x'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \bigr)^2 
+ \bigl( y'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \bigr)^2 \\
&= \bigl( x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}t^2. 
\end{align}

By the way, in the special case that $y = f(x)$, where the parameter $t$ is extraneous since we can take $t=x$, this reduces to the familiar
$$
\mathrm{d}s^2 = \bigl( 1 + f'(x)^2 \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}x^2.
$$

---

Now, let's use polar coordinates, related by
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x &= r \cos\theta \\
y &= r \sin\theta
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
First of all,
\begin{align} 
\mathrm{d}x &= \mathrm{d} \bigl( r \cos\theta \bigr) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \bigl( r \cos\theta \bigr) 
\, \mathrm{d}r
+  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \bigl( r \cos\theta \bigr) 
\, \mathrm{d}\theta \\[2pt] 
&= \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}r - r \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}
Similarly, we can calculate $\mathrm{d}y$ (try it yourself before revealing the spoiler)

> \begin{align} \mathrm{d}y &= \mathrm{d} \bigl( r \sin\theta \bigr) \\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \bigl( r \sin\theta \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}r +  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \bigl( r \sin\theta \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\[2pt] &= \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}r + r \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \end{align}

Putting these together to find $\mathrm{d}s^2$ and simplifying with a bit of algebra (again, try it yourself),

> \begin{align} \mathrm{d}s^2 &= \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 \\ &= \bigl( \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}r - r \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \bigr)^2 + \bigl( \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}r + r \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \bigr)^2 \\ &= \bigl( \cos^2\theta \, \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta^2 - 2r\sin\theta\cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta \bigr) \\ &\qquad{} + \bigl( \sin^2\theta \, \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \cos^2\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + 2r\sin\theta\cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta \bigr) \\ &= \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta^2 \end{align}

Now, if the radial coordinate is a function of the argument, i.e. $r = f(\theta)$, then $\mathrm{d}r = f'(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$ and

> \begin{align} \mathrm{d}s^2 &= \bigl( f'(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \bigr)^2 + f(\theta)^2  \, \mathrm{d}\theta^2 \\ &= \bigl( f'(\theta)^2 + f(\theta)^2 \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}\theta^2, \end{align}

which gives the arc length formula
$$
L = \int_a^b \sqrt{f'(\theta)^2 + f(\theta)^2} \, \mathrm{d}\theta 
\tag{$^\dagger$}
$$
for $\theta \in [a, b]$.

$^\dagger$This is the same as the formula you're looking for, but with the functional relationship made more explicit by using the symbol $f$. It can be confusing when $r$ is the name of the function and the output values at the same time, where you write things like $r = r(\theta)$. *Tom**ay**to. Tom**ah**to.* It's up to you how you write it.

Comment: Where did you learn the usage of notation such as $dx = d(r \cos \theta) = \frac{\partial}{ \partial r} (r \cos \theta) d r + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(r \cos \theta) d \theta$? In my calculus education, I basically learned to differentiate and integrate but often I see people using really weird identities I never saw before. I asked about other of these identities [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479831/25805).

Comment: I don't know "what's happening" because I went into my undergraduate course with almost no mastery of basic mathematics. But it seems to me that using such identities is something akin to "calculus with infinitesimals" which were regarded as "non rigorous" or something? Perhaps everything I'm saying is nonsense but: I don't know if they did cover this in my courses but I couldn't pay attention because I was struggling, I don't know if I was hit by some educational trend about "infinitesimals and rigor" and they did omit this?

Comment: Anyway, the books where I mostly see this notation are always more "vintage". I'd really like to learn to use this kind of notation and also be able to derive and understand such identities myself. Can you recommend me something?

Comment: I'm trying to show you a brief way to do these calculations using the language of [differential forms](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Differential_form). These techniques are rigorous, even if I'm not explaining in this limited space the language of vector bundles and other tools of differential geometry that support them.

Comment: At the core, though, a calculation like 
$$
\mathrm{d}(\sin\theta) 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta 
= \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta 
$$
shows the mechanics of a *substitution* like you learn in an integral calculus class, e.g. $\mathrm{d}u = u'(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$ so that 
$$
\int f(\sin\theta) \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta 
= \int f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u. 
$$